# Markdown não está funcionando no README no Github?

Tags: github, markdown

É só colocar por exemplo no arquivo `README` o símbolo `#` antes de um título que o Github automaticamente transforma para `h1` ou tem que configurar ou baixar alguma coisa para o Markdown funcionar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O arquivo deve ter extensão `.md` para o *engine* do GitHub saber que deve processar o Markdown. Não precisa fazer mais nada, a não ser usar a marcação especial do Markdown. De fato o `#` transforma em `<H1>` no HTML.

Comment: certo cara, exatamente isto, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É necessário dar um espeço depois da marcação.

Ex:

```
# Seu título h1.
## Seu título h2
- sua lista
```

Veja a lista completa de marcadores:

https://help.github.com/en/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax